# Rooting Gionee P5W

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rooting

When I tried Kingroot apk to root, it says that there is no root strategy available for my phone. 
Is there any working method available for rooting my android phone?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer I take no responsibility for this info whenever you root a device there is a chance that you will brick your device.**

1. To root follow my answer at this post [Backup/dump kernel image (and
   full ROM) without root for Mediatek Devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices/203874#203874)
2. Now copy the boot.img file you got from this procedure and place it
   in the Download folder on your device.
3. Download Magisk Manger from here [[2018.10.22] Magisk v17.3 - Root & Universal Systemless Interface [Android 5.0+]](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445)
4. Install it on your device and run it.
5. Select Install and then select again install. Now select Patch Boot Image File.
6. The app will tell you where the file was created, flash this file to your device and you should be rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Download the .zip file of latest version supersu to your computer

Connect your phone to the computer using a USB cable

Drag the SuperSU zip to device internal storage or SD card

Reboot your phone into TWRP recovery (Method to boot each device into TWRP recovery varies and Google for correct method for your device)

Make sure to back up the device in tWRP recovery]using Backup option

Click the Install button

Scroll down find SuperSU ZIP file you transferred

Tap the SuperSU zip

Swipe to confirm the flash

When the process is completed, tap the “Wipe cache/Dalvik” button that appears and swipe to confirm

Tap the “Reboot System” button to boot back into Android

Now the device is rooted and you will be asked to install SuperSU APK.Do not let TWRP install SuperSU APK itself do it yourself.

Comment: "Since your device is using Android lollipop": and why then did OP tag it "Marshmallow"? Just wondering; of course it might be the OP who's wrong; if so, maybe you [edit] your answer and point out what makes you think it must be LP – and maybe add if it works on MM too?